# Jest - unexpected identifier - Component testing w Jest react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo, enzyme

I keep getting this error when trying to test a button component. I have changed Jest's config settings here and there but nothing has worked, can anyone tell me the answer so I can stop pulling my hair out?

**I am using expo to demo the app, the problem seems to lie within the font that it's trying to render on the nav button, Jest/React doesn't understand it.**

The failure:
 FAIL  *tests*/Components/NavigationButton.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
C:\..\node_modules\@expo\vector-icons\Zocial.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import Zocial from './build/Zocial';
                                                                                                ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-elements/src/helpers/getIconType.js:1:1)
```

NavigationButton.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';



const NavigationButton =(props) => {
    return (
        <Button data-test="nav_button"
        icon={<Icon name={props.icon} size={30} color="white" style={styles.iconStyle} />}
        raised
        color="white"
        buttonStyle={styles.button}
        title={props.title}onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(props.navName)}
    />
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        minWidth:150,
        alignSelf:'center',
    },
    iconStyle:{
        marginHorizontal:10
    }
});

export default withNavigation(NavigationButton);
```

NavigationButton.test.js:

```
/**
* @format
*/

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { findByTestAtt } from '../../Utils/test_utils';
import NavigationButton from '../../src/Components/NavigationButton'


// Note: this is just for use with Jest snapshot testing
// and comes packaged with react-native init project.
// You do not need this if using Enzyme 'toMatchSnapshot' etc.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

// setup for shallow rendering component, saves having to do it in every test in this file
const  setup = (props = {}) => {
 const component = shallow(<NavigationButton {...props} />);
 return component;
};


describe('NavigationButton tests: ', () => {

let component;
beforeEach(() => {
 component = setup();
});


it('Button renders correctly: ', () => {
  console.log(component.debug());
  const wrapper = findByTestAtt(component, 'nav_button');
  expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
});



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `jest-expo` preset solved the problem for me. The documentation explains it well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expo. The issue seemed to be that the `import` keyword wasn't being transformed, I'm not clear on why but it came up in an issue here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5296

Comment: Yeah I eventually decided to use the Jest-Expo config. I followed the docs currently on Jest.io and changed it. I wasn't sure whether to set the config to Enzyme, React Native, or Jest-Expo. Thanks for that!